# Multiple azure cloud services in a single solution

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cloud-services

I'm in the process of implementing a series of web api services that must be separated and isolated from each other when running. For this, each service is a different Asp.NET Web Api project, but for simplicity and cohesion, we have it all in the same solution.

We plan on deploying the services using Azure Cloud Services but I can't find a way to set up the projects so each one is published on a different CloudService.

Thanks

Comment: Why? You just need to create a publish profile for each webapi project

Comment: Can't you just have separate cloud project for each webapi project in your solution and publish them separately?

Comment: Thanks @ThiagoCustodio and GauravMantri, this is what I ended up doing, I wasn't sure if it was a posibility.